# You can't put a flower in an a**hole and call it a vase

Tags: pronouns, objects, antecedents

I am not trying to be funny (other than the fact that the joke is, in and of itself, funny).
I'm asking someone to parse this for me. Seems to me it should be something like, "You can't put a flower in an a**hole and say it's in a vase."
Or, "You can't put a flower in an a**hole and call the a**hole a vase."
Isn't "flower" the object of the sentence and therefore what the pronoun "it" stands for?

Comment: Here, *"it"* stands for ahole. English pronouns are much more flexible that that. You need to use context  to figure out what they stand for. If the sentence was *"you can't put a flower in an aquarium and call it a fish"*, *"it"* would stand for *"flower"*.

Comment: It refers to a flower.

Comment: @Rathony In the OP's original quote, the 'it' *does not* refer to the flower, it refers to the receptacle.

Comment: @MarvMills Your are absolutely right. In the body, it refers to a flower. (I didn't read the title) :-)

Comment: One may also interpret "it" as the  whole object: the  a**hole plus the flower. Is a vase without  a flower a vase? Could  be a glass.

Comment: In all the times I have had a flower there I have never once failed to call it a vase.

Comment: When you've solved this level-one puzzler, consider taking on the more-complex question of whether Yankee Doodle uses the term _macaroni_ to refer to his hat, to a feather, to his hat with a feather in it, or to the act of sticking a feather in his hat.

Comment: I would interpret "it" to refer to the resulting construction of flower and the object holding it.  And "vase", as commonly used, can refer just to the container, or it can refer to a container with flowers.  (In fact, a tin can containing a flower arrangement would be properly considered to be a "vase", even though the can is an undistinguished coffee can.)  But, regardless, aphorisms such as the subject one are allowed a certain amount of "poetic license" -- don't overthink it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> You can't put a flower in an a***hole and say it's in a vase

and

> You can't put a flower in an a***hole and call the a***hole a vase

would both also be valid paraphrasings of the same sentence, but the original works too. Although grammatically the "it" could refer to either the flower or the a***hole in

> You can't put a flower in an a***hole and call it a vase,

context and semantics are enough to distinguish between the two possibilities. I can't see any reason why we would call a flower a vase because it's in an a***hole, but calling the a***hole a vase because it contains a flower would make more sense. That reasoning tells us what the "it" must refer to.

Nice saying, btw :-)

Comment: Thanx, rand!...

Answer (score 2):

There's no rule that "it" refers to the object of a sentence; it can generally refer to any previous noun or noun phrase. It can even be used without an explicit antecedent (the so-called "[dummy it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun#Dummy_subjects)").

(Your question reminds me a little of this one: [What does this "it" refer to?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/293705/77227))

Answer (score 1):

This, like many pithy folk sayings, is really a piece of poetry.  As such, the rhythm is at least as important as the grammar.  To expect it to conform to formal structural expectations is to critically misunderstand its function and register.